# Wildcard cert installed in Apache but subdomain fails browser check

Tags: apache, ssl, dns

I have an apache instance running with my domain's wildcard cert (ie *.mydomain.com) installed and when I surf to the URL site.mydomain.com, cert passes browser check without any issue.

Now I created a subdomain in DNS, lab.mydomain.com and created a record for the same server to be site.lab.mydomain.com. The cert did not change at all, however, now browser is complaining. Below is the Chrome error.

```
Certificate Error
There are issues with the site's certificate chain (net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID).
```

What exactly did I miss or misunderstand?

Answer (score 1):

`site.lab.mydomain.com` does not match the certificate for `*.mydomain.com`. A wildcard matches only a single label, i.e. `*.lab.mydomain.com` would be needed instead.

Comment: The place I bought the cert from, NameCheap, which sold me a RapidSSL wildcard cert said it should work *.blah.mydomain.com. I assume that is completely wrong then?

Comment: @Eroji. yes, this is wrong. There are no certificates which can include every sub-domain and also every sub-sub-domain because a wildcard matches only a single label and multiple wildcards are not allowed. See also http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/52478/why-does-firefox-not-trust-this-us-government-ssl-certificate/52479#52479.